# weblogic server hangs in running phase in Jdeveloper 12.2.1.4 when i try to start Integrated web logic server

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, jdeveloper, weblogic11g

`<Aug 11, 2020 5:08:07,659 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <The server started in RUNNING mode.>  <Aug 11, 2020 5:08:07,773 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.>`

It never says server has been started successfully. I'm facing this issue from the time I started using Jdeveloper 12.2.1.4. I tried to delete the default domain.. Cleaned up the folder system<> folder form AppData/Roaming but still the issue is not yet solved

Comment: RUNNING means the server has been started, what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: It shows running but it is not really running.. When it says Integrated Weblogic Server started successfully the console and all comes up but in this case even in the running mode it doesnt really start

Comment: Is this the AdminServer? Could you somehow share the whole log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this was to disable the proxy settings in tools-> preferences -> Web browser and proxy -> set the proxy to no proxy